# Attempting to access file outside of directory - when trying to access member profile

Tags: members, ee3

I had other issues with avatars, but a fresh install of 3.1.1 seemed to resolve that. Now, when I went into the member profile on a fresh install, it displayed proper the first time. When I went back in the second time, I got this error:

```
Exception Caught

Attempting to access file outside of directory.
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\system\ee\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\File\Directory.php:28

Stack Trace: hide details

#0     
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\system\ee\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Filesystem\Filesystem.php(306): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\File\Directory->normalize('facebook_1.png')

#1 
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\system\ee\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Members\Profile\Settings.php(120): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Filesystem\Filesystem->exists('facebook_1.png')

#2
[internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Members\Profile\Settings->index()

#3 
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\system\ee\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core.php(191): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

#4     
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\system\ee\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core.php(94): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)

#5 
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\system\ee\EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Boot\boot.php(138): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))

#6
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\public_html\admin\index.php(143): require_once('C:\\GIT\\Producti...')

#6
C:\GIT\Production\stkhomes.net\public_html\admin\index.php(143): require_once('C:\\GIT\\Producti...')
```

This happens on both production server and development server.

PHP Version 5.3.29
EE Version 3.1.1

---

*** UPDATE

It is happening here:

```
protected function normalize($path)
    {
        $path = $this->root.'/'.$path;

        if (strpos($path, '..') !== 0)
        {
            throw new FilesystemException('Attempting to access file outside of directory.');
        }

        return $path;
    }
```

If I echo out the path, it is : `C:/GIT/Production/stkhomes.net/public_html/images/avatars/facebook_1.png`

The statement should equate to `False` thus returning the variable `$path`.

If I comment out this section:

```
if (strpos($path, '..') !== 0)
            {
                throw new FilesystemException('Attempting to access file outside of directory.');
            }
```

The page loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to be expecting `$this->root` to be a relative file path (think something like `../my_web_root/`), but is instead getting a full server path (`C:/GIT/production/etc`).

Check all of your file upload preferences and path settings for your installations are correct. If you're 100% sure your paths are correct, this sounds like a possible bug, possibly connected to Windows file paths. I would recommend contacting EllisLab at team@ellislab.com.

Comment: Where are the file path settings in 3? For whatever reason, 3 has thrown me for a loop.

Comment: Even the production server has the same issue (Non-Windows)...

Exception Caught

Attempting to access file outside of directory.

/home/stkhomes/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/File/Directory.php:28

Comment: Sounding even slightly more bug-like. Investigate the code that generates that method's parent class `$root` variable.

Comment: The code just uses the PHP `realpath()` which, in this case, generates `/home/stkhomes/public_html/images/avatars/` for the root. Then rebuilds the full path from the root by appending '/' and the passed string. In this sample, I chose the bunny, so: `/home/stkhomes/public_html/images/avatars/zombie_bunny.png`